# $X=\mathrm{Spec}\ k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)\Longrightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(X)=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

An exercise of Hartshorne shows that, given $A= k[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$, $\mathrm{Cl}(A)=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

> I must prove that $\mathrm{Pic}(\mathrm{Spec}\ A)=0$, thus giving a counter-example to $\mathrm{Pic}=\mathrm{Cl}$.

My attempt was to consider some UFD $B$, e.g. $k[x,y,z]$ itself, send it to $A$, and obtain a map from $Pic(\rm Spec\ B)$ to $Pic(\rm Spec\ A)$, and then hope that this is surjective. This would conclude since $B$ UFD implies $Pic(\rm Spec\ B)=0$.

Can this work? Any hints are welcome.

Comment: I don't think this is the way to do it: I don't see any way to prove that surjectivity apart from proving ${\rm Pic}(A)=0$. From my point of view, the first thing to do is to show that $A$ is normal, so that you know that ${\rm Pic}(A)\subseteq{\rm Cl}(A)=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Once you know this, you only have two possibilities, and you can try to exclude the wrong one.

Comment: **HINT** $\mathrm{Pic} (X) \simeq H^1(X,\mathscr O_X)$ and $X$ is affine.

Comment: I think maybe there is a typo in the hint above $Pic(X) \cong H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_x^*)$. Also, wouldn't this only be helpful if $A$ is a UFD? I'm just curious what you have in mind.

Comment: I don't think the hint is the right way to go, if only because cohomology hasn't been introduced at this point in Hartshorne...

Comment: Just to know it, is $\mathcal O_X^*$ a quasi-coherent sheaf? Since it is a group sheaf and not a module, I am not very accustomed to it, but perhaps the same results hold...

Comment: $O_X^{*}$ is not a quasi-coherent sheaf. This also affects the hint, since $Pic(X)$ is $H^1(O_X^*)$, and $X$ being affine does not imply that it is zero. There are affine schemes with nontrivial Picard group (for example a smooth quadric surface minus a hyperplane section)